# Write to properties file on Wildfly which is loaded by ClassLoader

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, properties, resources, wildfly

I am loading properties on an Wildfly application server like this:

```
public String getPropertyValue(String propertyName) throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream;
    Properties properties = new Properties();

    inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propertyFileName);

    if (inputStream != null) {
        properties.load(inputStream);
    } else {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("property file '" + propertyFileName + "' not found in the classpath");
    }

    inputStream.close();
    String property = properties.getProperty(propertyName);
    LOG.debug("Property {} with value {} loaded.", propertyName, property);
    return property;
}
```

Now I want to write to that very same file. How do I do that correctly? I tried around with new File(configurationFileName), but that creates a new File in a different directory, and I tried around with URL/URI of file from classloader, but that doesn't seem to work either. What is the correct way to do this? 
Thx for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't and you shouldn't. I would use a database table to store and load properties. Or if it shall be a properties-file, then store it somewhere external via a file path, but not via the class path.

Answer (score 0):

```
try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File( getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(propertyName).toURI()))){
    properties.store(out,"My Comments);
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. Imparting the underlying logic is more important than just giving the code, because it helps the OP and other readers fix this and similar issues themselves.

Comment: Get an OutputStream on the file, use the store method from the java.util.Properties to save changes. That's all

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I get the exception "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI scheme is not "file""

Comment: What is it ? Do you get a VFS uri ?

Answer (score 0):

Raoul Duke is actually right, doing the properties via file raises a lot of problems. I will soon switch to DB for keeping those. In the mean time I did this: When I write properties, they are written to a newly created file. When I read properties, I load the "old" ones, and then create a new properties object with the old ones as defaults, in which I then load the new file.

```
private Properties loadProperties() throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream;
    Properties defaultProperties = new Properties();
    inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(defaultPropertyFileName);
    if (inputStream != null) {
        defaultProperties.load(inputStream);
    } else {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Property file '" + defaultPropertyFileName + "' not found in the classpath");
    }
    inputStream.close();
    Properties allProps = new Properties(defaultProperties);
    try {
        allProps.load(new FileInputStream(new File(updatedPropertyFileName)));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        LOG.error("Error loading properties: {}", ex.toString());
        return defaultProperties;
    }
    return allProps;
}
```

I marked his answer right, since I am technically not writing to the file I wanted to, plus this is only a workaround and his solution is way better and cleaner.